# Generating output in a Windows Form App

Tags: winforms

I am working on a windows form app like most development it is usually useful to see output. I am wondering what methods you use to see output in a windows form app.

PS. I am new to visual studio in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set some Labels around and display text on them:

```
Label.Text = "Some Text";
```

And DataGridView controls for information from tables, and for a better insight, you can set breakpoints in your code by clicking the far-left part of your code editing area. When the program reaches to that point it'll stop and you can hover your variables and objects for a better view of their insides...

Oh, and also VS has a "Locals" window when you run your project, that shows all the objects and variables being used and some information about them.

Answer (score 0):

- the user interface (a grid or other
  controls on a form)
- a report (like Crystal)
- a file (.txt)
- a database table updated